# Irrigation system: Backflow Preventer -> Master Valve vs Master Valve -> Backflow Preventer

Tags: valve, irrigation, backflow-preventer

I am in the process of designing my irrigation system, and I saw many people install the backflow preventer (reduced pressure zone device) first and then connect to an automatic master valve.

However, I'm debating whether I should move the automatic master valve before the backflow preventer as RPZD is very expensive, and my theory is if I give it less pressure, it will be last longer.

What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: why do you need an automatic master valve?

Comment: Location of backflow preventers in relationship to valves could be dictated by code.  Make sure you understand the requirements before you start to make changes.